# Create a Google Doc in landscape mode

Tags: google-docs, orientation, landscape

How do I create a Google Doc in landscape mode?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Go to **File** → **Page setup...** and change to Landscape there.

[image]

[image]

The current view does not appear to change but next time you go to print preview, you should see that it is formatted landscape.

Comment: I have some lines that are longer than 73 characters long that I do not want to word-wrap.  Putting a "Do not view this page in fixedwith view" warning at the beginning of the document seems primitive, but it looks like that's the best that can be done.